# Adding linked list together and printing the result

Tags: c++, list, sum-of-digits

My problem is asking to have two linked lists where each node has one value and add them together into a different linked list. But, in order to get the digits of the list, I will have to do the modulo and division operator to shift my decimal and get the digits. I am using the power function as an increment of my index through the list and able to add them together. However, in the end is not printing my output. Everything looks fine, but the new linked list is not showing up. This is what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

class elem {
public:

    int data;
    elem * next;
    elem * prev;
    elem()
    {
        next = prev = NULL;
    }
};
elem *head = NULL;

int num(elem * head) { //Putting the head in the last element
    int mem = 0;
    int powr = 0;
    for (elem * p = head; p != NULL; p = p->next) {
        mem += p->data * pow(10, powr);
        powr++; //Increments the list +1
    }

    return mem; //Returns the sum 
    /*
        ex. first element is 6, then it will be 6 x 10^0 = 6
            second element is 1, then it will become 1 x 10^1 = 10
            third element is 7, then it will become 7 x 10^2 = 700
            total mem = 700 + 10 + 6 = 716
            linked list form (7 -> 1 -> 6)
    */
}

int digit(int value) {
    int mem = 0;
    while (value > 0) {
        value /= 10;
        mem++;
    }
    return value;
}



elem * listSum(elem * listOne, elem * listTwo) {
    int temp1 = num(listOne); //List #1
    int temp2 = num(listTwo); //List #2
    int sum = temp1 + temp2; //New sum
    int digits = digit(sum); //New element with the sum of both

    elem * list = NULL;
    elem * last = NULL;
    for (int ii = 0; ii<digits; ii++) {
        elem * p = new elem;
        p->next = NULL;
        if (list == NULL) {
            list = p;
        }
        else {
            last->next = p;
        }
        p->data = sum % 10; //Gets the digit
        sum /= 10; //Reduces the decimal
        last = p; //Adds the new value into the last (from 7->1->6 it is going to become 617)
    }
    return list;
}

void main() {
    //Make first list
    // 7 -> 1 -> 6 -> NULL
    elem * a1 = new elem;
    a1->data = 7;
    elem * b1 = new elem;
    b1->data = 1;
    elem * c1 = new elem;
    c1->data = 6;

    a1->next = b1;
    b1->next = c1;
    c1->next = NULL;
    elem * firstHead = a1;

    //Make second list
    // 5 -> 9 -> 2 -> NULL
    elem * a2 = new elem;
    a2->data = 5;
    elem * b2 = new elem;
    b2->data = 9;
    elem * c2 = new elem;
    c2->data = 2;

    a2->next = b2;
    b2->next = c2;
    c2->next = NULL;
    elem * secondHead = a2;

    elem * newHead = listSum(firstHead, secondHead);
    /*
        ( 7 -> 1 -> 6) + (5 -> 9 -> 2) would be 617 + 295 = 3rd new node
    */
    for (elem * p = newHead; p != NULL; p = p->next) {
        cout << p->data;

        //Output should be: 2 -> 1 -> 9. Which is 912
    }

}
```

As a test case, I made a print function to see if is printing the list for the sum, but it says that is empty. My other values looks fine when it prints. Any thoughts?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Start with figuring out why `digit` always returns zero.

Comment: If you're implementing arbitrary-precision numbers, you're supposed to do the addition digit by digit, not by computing the numbers first.

Comment: @molbdnilo I was returning to the value in my digit function. I saw the problem so I changed the return to mem instead. Therefore, the later code was reading my total of digits (mem) and run through it carefully thanks to the previous commenter with the little advice. The result ended up with 2 1 9, which is 912 and it is pretty good. Can you tell me how I am implementing arbitrary-precision numbers? I am curious about it.

Comment: @ZeidTisnes I don't see the point of this (school?) exercise other than for arbitrarily large integers, in which case you're expected to handle lists of arbitrary length. Think about what happens if you try to add two fifty-digit integers.

Comment: @molbdnilo pretty much school, but I was looking for input suggestions. And yeah, I see what you are saying now, it will probably not work with bigger numbers